# Codeigniter image gallery

Tags: image, codeigniter, gallery

First sorry if its a stupid guestion but im a really big beginner.

I would like to make an image gallyer similar to facebook, but what i dont really understand is te logic.

I made a multi image upload, it saves the image nam and extension to the database with a title .
A folder is created by the title name.

My problem is i dont know how to select them.
What i mean a person uploads 20 images in folder hello, on the page show the hello with one of the thumbnails and when i click it redirects me to the other pictures.

So tihs is the logic what i dont really understand, and i dont want anybody to write this for me, i only would like the opinion or a hint form a more expreienced developer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DB, keep track of the cover photo for each album. Since you probably want to allow users to name albums you might as well save that in there, too.

Table::albums
- id
- name
- photo_id //cover photo, or even the link to the image can be saved here directly if you don't like joins
- ...
Table::album_has_photos
- id
- album_id
- name
- url
- ...

To view the album overview: in your album controller extract the album names, cover photo links from table::albums and send those to the view;
In your view set up a link around each of the cover photos to a controller that loads the album contents from table::album_has_photos;
Display photos from one album and add visual effects.
Ooptional: add pagination to the album overview.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea would be to keep the url of the images in the db (full url or relative - doesn't matter) and possibly the gallery id (if you're using more than one gallery). Then, you'd use the [Database class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) to select all the image urls and send that data to the view. In the view, you can use a `foreach` loop to generate an appropriate  tag for each of the selected images. After that, you could possibly add a lightbox plugin of some sort to have a nice popups when you click on thumbnails.